# C# XDocument element is outside his parent element

Tags: c#

Using linq xDocument I want to check if an element is outside his parent.

Sample XML:

```
<document>
<x>
<p>text</p>
</x>--this is correct

<p>some text</p> --this should be inside <x> tag
<x>
<p>text</p>
</x>--this is correct
</document>
```

Expected:

```
<document>
<x>
<p>text</p>
</x>
<x>
<p>some text</p>
<p>text</p>
</x>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinqToXml gives a lot of information about the elements in the xml.
On of the properties of the XElements is the .Parent property.

So u can use something like this

```
var unexpectedParagraphs = xdoc.Root
      .Elements()
      .Where(x => x.Parent.Name != "x");
```

This will return any elements that are direct children of the root where their parent is not named 'x'.

You can check this link to get started with linqToXml if this is new to you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx

Comment: var nodes = xdoc.Descendants().Elements("child").Where(x => x.Parent.Name.LocalName != "parent"); --  got it.. thanks everyone

Comment: you can shorten that a bit xdoc.Descendants("child").Where(..)